# How do I compile Twitter Bootstrap 3.0 using Windows 8

Tags: html, css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap

I am wondering how do I compile Twitter Bootstrap using Less on a Windows machine? This is the only tutorial I can find, however this failed when installed lessc (saying lessc is not in the npm registry). Anyway I was not optimistic this would work since it's for BS2 and not 3.0

How can I compile bootstrap 3.0 on windows to set the less values?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're asking about compiling bootstrap LESS sources?

It is not necessary to involve `lessc`, there are number of apps on Windows, that perfectly handle LESS2CSS compilation:

1. [SimpLESS](http://wearekiss.com/simpless)
2. [WinLess](http://winless.org/)
3. [Prepros](http://alphapixels.com/prepros/)

(Prepros is my personal favorite. Compiles LESS, SASS, CoffeScript and dozen of other things. Supports autocompiling and live reload as well.)